# Not able to boot kernel in qemu

Tags: x86, gdb, kernel, embedded-linux, qemu

I need to setup the kernel debugging environment using qemu and gdb.

```
qemu-system-i386 -kernel linux/linux-3.9.4/arch/i386/boot/bzImage -hda disk.img -append "root=/dev/sda1" -s -S
```

I need to pass the kernel as argument. However, when I run this the start sequence fails saying "Cannot open root device."

I also referred the documentation but there is none providing specific info. Is there any pre-tested hd image where the kernel arguments are known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can actually be the result of an incorrect kernel configuration. If your kernel doesn't have support for the required hardware (or file system) built in it can't mount your rootfs.

That's a fairly common situation with many distributions. Instead they rely on initial ram disks which load modules or perform whatever other work is required to be able to mount the rootfs.

You may need to either adjust your kernel config or create an initrd. (Loading initrds is supported by Qemu using '-initrd')